# Create a subset of debian repo

Tags: debian, apt

I need to create a subset of an existing repository that contains certain packages. The dependencies of these packages need to be satisfied.
Now, I know how to create an Apt repository from a given set of .deb files using dpkg-scanpackages, but the process doesn't satisfy dependencies. I can do it by hand, but it's tedious and there's chance something gets missed.

Is there a more automated way to satisfy dependencies in a repository?

Comment: Maybe helpful: http://askubuntu.com/questions/80655/how-can-i-check-dependency-list-for-a-deb-package

Comment: dpkg -I prints all information about package, not just a list of dependencies. Also that list includes things such as version numbers and logical operations, so it's not easily scriptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be interested in [aptly](http://www.aptly.info) - it is a tool to ease the problems of debian repository management. Its [repo import](http://www.aptly.info/doc/aptly/repo/import/) functionality imports packages and its dependencies and sounds exactly like the tool you are looking for.

As far as I understand documentation (did not have a use-case for aptly yet unfortunately), it is possible you have to mirror the repository you want to create a subset of though.

Comment: You don't have to mirror the whole repository. `aptly mirror create -filter=<pkgname> -filter-with-deps  ...` does the trick.